# Android Studio Bot repeats the old conversation between they new

Tags: android, bots, message, rasa

I need help, if anyone can assist.
When I try to run my Rasa based bot in the Android Studio emulator, at first it all goes well and the conversation is initiated fine with the use of a "hello". The moment I use the "hello" again, the bot does reply with the requested information, but also starts to repeat the older conversation in between the new one, and not just what the Bot had said, but also what the user had sent.
When I run the Rasa bot in the terminal of my Visual Studio, it runs fine and shows no issues, so I assumed the issue has to do with the way the AS stores the sent messages.

I tried adjusting the way my MessageList is stored and handled, but nothing was successful.
Does anyone have any suggestions? I have been working on this particular issue for a couple of weeks now, with no result.